# C++ Dll doesn't work on a system not having visual studio installed

Tags: c++, dll

I am creating a C++ dll which properly works on the machine where I build it, but when I try to test the same dll (using rundll32.exe) from a different machine on which visual studio is not installed it reflects an error : "There was a problem starting dll; Specified module can't be found"

How do I write a dll so that it will work with any of the windows machine where I import the same?

Comment: You haven't told us anything about your project's dependencies, build settings, platform (arch, OS, version), etc...

Comment: I am building the code on windows 10, with debug mode (tried with release also ) . I am unable to use it on Windows Server 2012, x64

Comment: Generally speaking, you cannot run Debug builds of Visual C++ programs on computers that don't have the exact same version of Visual Studio installed.

Answer (score 0):

Very likely you need to install the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 20XX on the target PC.

Comment: Tried post installing Redistributable  as well , still it pops same error